# Android - how to capture or detect that an application is being closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i need to make some http calls when the user closes the app. It shouldn't be releated to an activity but to the application.

is there a possibility to get application will close event ?

Is there a way to do it ? if yes, how ?

Comment: I don't think you can tell when your entire application is closing. Such callbacks exist for activities, but are not guaranteed to be called. Is it possible to do the http calls in each activity's onPause() method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Override this method in your all activities and put your code in OnDestroy

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()...");
    super.onDestroy();
     //Put your http calls code here . It always called when your activity close
}
```

Comment: no i cannot use that, the onDestroy, will be called when the activity is destroyed. I need to get the event when the application is about to be destroyed.

Comment: assuming i use the onDestroy, how will i know if the application will really quit or if it is just the current activity being destroyed ?